# Paint a graph on JPanel

Tags: java, graph, graphics, jframe, jpanel

I just started to use a graphic on Java so be patient if I ask something obvious, I need to paint the graph of a function in a JPanel, the graph has to be painted in a for loop, while the new x and y are generated. This is the cycle:

```
for(int i=0;i<iter;i++) {
    xv=(int)x0[0];
    yv=(int)x0[1];
    x0[0]=d1[0][0]*((e[0][1]+f[0][1])*x0[1]+b[0]);
    x0[1]=d1[1][1]*((e[1][0]+f[1][0])*x0[0]+b[1]);
    x=(int)x0[0];
    y=(int)x0[1];

    g2.drawLine(xv,yv,x,y);
}
```

I don't know how to display the line in the JPanel and since I just need the working graph if there are some simpler solutions I'm ready to learn.
Thank you in advance.

EDIT: this is my full code

```
    /*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

package jacobi;



import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
/**
 *
 * @author Stella
 */

public class NewJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {
double a[][]=new double [2][2];
double b[]=new double[2];
double x0[]=new double[2];
double d1[][]=new double[2][2];
boolean appl=false;
double d[][]=new double [2][2];
double e[][]=new double [2][2];
double f[][]=new double [2][2];
int iter;

int x=0;
int y=0;
int xv=0;
int yv=0;
    /**
     * Creates new form NewJFrame
     */
    public NewJFrame() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jFrame1 = new javax.swing.JFrame();
        jFrame2 = new javax.swing.JFrame();
        jFrame3 = new javax.swing.JFrame();
        jFrame4 = new javax.swing.JFrame();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton3 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jLabel5 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel6 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jButton4 = new javax.swing.JButton();

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jFrame1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jFrame1.getContentPane());
        jFrame1.getContentPane().setLayout(jFrame1Layout);
        jFrame1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jFrame1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 400, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        jFrame1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jFrame1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 300, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jFrame2Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jFrame2.getContentPane());
        jFrame2.getContentPane().setLayout(jFrame2Layout);
        jFrame2Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jFrame2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 400, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        jFrame2Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jFrame2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 300, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jFrame3Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jFrame3.getContentPane());
        jFrame3.getContentPane().setLayout(jFrame3Layout);
        jFrame3Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jFrame3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 400, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        jFrame3Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jFrame3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 300, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jFrame4Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jFrame4.getContentPane());
        jFrame4.getContentPane().setLayout(jFrame4Layout);
        jFrame4Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jFrame4Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 400, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        jFrame4Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jFrame4Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 300, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jLabel1.setText("Prima equazione");

        jLabel2.setText("Da generare");

        jLabel3.setText("Seconda equazione");

        jLabel4.setText("Da generare");

        jButton1.setText("Genera matrice");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton2.setText("Controlla se il metodo è applicabile");
        jButton2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton2ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton3.setText("Risolvi equazione");
        jButton3.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton3ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jLabel5.setText("Da controllare");

        jLabel6.setText("Da risolvere");

        jButton4.setText("Genera grafico");
        jButton4.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton4ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(jLabel6, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addComponent(jButton3)
                            .addComponent(jLabel2)
                            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                    .addComponent(jLabel1)
                                    .addComponent(jButton2))
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                                    .addComponent(jLabel4)
                                    .addComponent(jLabel3)))
                            .addComponent(jButton1)
                            .addComponent(jButton4)
                            .addComponent(jLabel5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 197, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addGap(0, 104, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel1)
                    .addComponent(jLabel3))
                .addGap(33, 33, 33)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel2)
                    .addComponent(jLabel4))
                .addGap(31, 31, 31)
                .addComponent(jButton1)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(jButton2)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(jLabel5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 23, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jButton3)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(jLabel6)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addComponent(jButton4)
                .addGap(38, 38, 38))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:
         for(int i=0; i<a.length; i++)
        { for(int j=0; j<a.length; j++)
        {   a[i][j]=(int)(Math.random()*10)+1;

        } 

        }

        for(int i=0;i<b.length;i++)
        {
            b[i]=(int)(Math.random()*10)+1;
            x0[i]=(int)(Math.random()*10)+1;
        }


 String c=a[0][0]+"x+"+a[0][1]+"y="+b[0];
 String d=a[1][0]+"x+"+a[1][1]+"y="+b[1];
jLabel2.setText(c);
jLabel4.setText(d);
    }                                        

    private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        if((Math.abs(a[0][0])>Math.abs(a[0][1]))&&(Math.abs(a[1][1])>Math.abs(a[1][0])))
        {
            jLabel5.setText("Il metodo di Jacobi puﾃｲ essere applicato.");
            appl=true;
        }
        else
        {

            for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
            {
                d[i][i]=a[i][i];

            }
            e[1][0]=-a[1][0];
            f[0][1]=-a[0][1];

            for (int i=0;i<2;i++)
            {
                d1[i][i]=(Math.pow(d[i][i],-1));
            }
            double bj[][]=new double [2][2];

                    bj[0][0]=(d1[0][0]*(e[0][0]+f[0][0]))+(d1[0][1]*(e[1][0]+f[1][0]));
                    bj[0][1]=(d1[0][0]*(e[0][1]+f[0][1]))+(d1[0][1]*(e[1][1]+f[1][1]));
                    bj[1][0]=(d1[1][0]*(e[0][0]+f[0][0]))+(d1[1][1]*(e[1][0]+f[1][0]));
                    bj[1][1]=(d1[1][0]*(e[0][1]+f[0][1]))+(d1[1][1]*(e[1][1]+f[1][1]));

        double norma = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            double sum = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
                sum= sum+(Math.abs(bj[i][j])); // compute the column sum
            }
            if (sum > norma) {
                norma = sum; // found a new largest column sum
            }
        }
                if(norma<=1)
                {
                    jLabel5.setText("Il metodo di Jacobi puﾃｲ essere applicato.");
                    appl=true;

                }
                else{

                 jLabel5.setText("Il metodo di Jacobi non può essere applicato.");
                }
}




    }                                        
boolean gr=false;
    private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:

        if(appl==true)

        {
            String ite=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Inserire il numero di iterazioni");
            iter=Integer.parseInt(ite);

            for(int i=0;i<iter;i++)

            {
                xv=(int)x0[0];
       yv=(int)x0[1];
    x0[0]=d1[0][0]*((e[0][1]+f[0][1])*x0[1]+b[0]);
    x0[1]=d1[1][1]*((e[1][0]+f[1][0])*x0[0]+b[1]);
    x=(int)x0[0];
     y=(int)x0[1];

       }
jLabel6.setText("I risultati dopo "+iter+" iterazioni sono: x1="+x0[0]+" e x2="+x0[1]);
        }
        if(appl==false){
            jLabel6.setText("Il metodo di Jacobi non può essere applicato.");
        }

    }                                        

    private void jButton4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:
      JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.getContentPane().add(new MainClass());

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(200,200);
    frame.setVisible(true);


    }                                        
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    g.drawLine(xv, yv, x, y);

  }


    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */

     public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new NewJFrame().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton3;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton4;
    private javax.swing.JFrame jFrame1;
    private javax.swing.JFrame jFrame2;
    private javax.swing.JFrame jFrame3;
    private javax.swing.JFrame jFrame4;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel5;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel6;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: im no math genious, but don't you calculate the points on your graph one by one? So for each i you get one x and one y? drawLine(x, y, x, y) should draw a single point. So calling this for each x and y you calculate should do the job no?

Comment: I need the old x and y (in xv and yv that "v" means old) and since this is part of a math method I'm afraid to screw it up if I start to edit x and y

Comment: do you have the original mathematical equation(not code version)? Did you come up with this for construct your self or do you have it form somewhere else?

Comment: It is the Jacobi method

Comment: Can you post a code snippet that can actually be executed? With variable declarations and initialization. Also, what kind of graph do you want to display. XY points? Lines? Should each pixel on the panel x axis represent one value on the mathematical x axis?

Comment: I'm trying to display a lines graph, since it should be a iterative method the graph should converge in a single point or something like that; i'm editing the original post with my full code.